# Does 1,845cM shared indicate possible half sibling?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna

I was adopted in 1958 when I was 14 months old.  I have finally found my birth mother and also that I had 2 half-brothers.  They told me that mom had had another baby when that she gave up for adoption in 1953.  Well, I recently turned in my DNA etc.  and one possible match really stands out, who matches many of the details I know about that earlier baby..  She also has turned in a DNA sample and we share 1845 cM's over 68 segments.  Is there a strong possibility she is my half-sister?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains information about a living person that may identify them.  In violation of the 100 year rule https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I have edited it to conform with our privacy policy.

Comment: @Chenmunka Every single genetic genealogy question we get (and especially the DNA relationship questions using paternity/sibling tests) is about living people.  Do you recommend closing them all?  Taking out the detailed information was proper.  The solution is editing, not closure.

Comment: @Chenmunka I agree with Cyn that editing out identifying information for potentially living people is the appropriate action.  You should also then flag the moderators using Other to alert them that redaction is likely to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

At 1845cM according to the Shared cM project, it is 100% likely that this is your Grandparent Aunt / Half Sibling / Niece / Grandchild.

Given an age difference of 5 years, you can discount grandparent and grandchild.  Aunt and niece are theoretically possible even with a 5 year difference, but half-sibling is very likely.